# Multiple Components of the same type, accessing a shared Resource in Angular 2

Tags: arrays, json, angular, components, communication

I'm fairly new to Angular, so i just need to clarify on something that has to do with accessing data, that are placed within a Service by multiple instances of a Component.

My question, mostly comes from the fact that all the angular examples i have seen over the internet or the documentation are basic examples, passing on string messages and not segments of Arrays.

Okay to start with, the basic architecture of the App is this:

(App-root)

(Child-1) | (Child-2) | ... | (Child-n)|

I have my AppComponent and nested inside the HTML template are some ChildComponents, which are created with an *ngFor.

I used *ngFor because i won't know from the beginning of the app, the exact number of ChildComponents that i will have to create. Let's say that i will be getting that number from a JSON file after an API call.

The JSON file from the API call, has also certain information in the format of :

```
[
{info for ChildComp},
{info for ChildComp},
{info for ChildComp}
]
```

(As you can see the number of the ChildComponents is the length of the JSON Array.)

The solution that i have thought of, for my first problem, is getting the data from the JSON in a Service, which can be accessed through out the whole application, but then i ran into the next problem:

**How can i distribute the objects found within the array of the JSON file, to the ChildComponents and keeping track which Child got which data...**

I tried using the **@input** method from the parentComponent, but the problem is that i don't want to pass on the whole Array, just parts of it and i would like to keep track of what is being passed over, so that i know the ChildComponents got their share of the data and no duplicates are to be found(except if the {info for ChildComp} is duplicated).

To me it seems as a parallel resource access problem, but the thing is that i haven't found a way to separate the generated ChildComponents and grant them access.

Your views on this problem will be much appreciated and welcome.
(i haven't posted code due to the fact that i haven't implemented anything yet and i am still stuck at the app component mapping stage)

Comment: i think i found some kind of a solution with this:
https://alligator.io/angular/viewchild-access-component/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ViewChildren -> Do-able but it gets really messy when there's DOM changes involved, especially when you get the "Expression has changed after it was checked" error...

Shared Service and emitting a Subject value -> Nice clean way but a bit messy around the part of indexing objects.

*ngFor and @Input passing on Index and other data -> Best solution up to the moment!!

Using Resolvers -> Great aproach, but only when you have the data ready and do not want it on demand.